# How do I calculate powers in java using recursion based on this identity

Tags: java

The Identity being, x<sup>n</sup> =   (x<sup>n/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>  for all values where n is even and greater than 0.

How would I do this using a recursion method?

I'm finding myself stuck, and this is what I've been working with

```
public static double power(double base, int power){
if (power == 0){
    return 1;
}

else if (power > 0 || power % 2 == 0){
    ???
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems fairly straightforward. You jst have to apply the formula and substitute the values rite? Or am I missing smthing?

Comment: Well I need to call upon itself to solve the problem, but I feel like the answer is right in front of my eyes but I'm not seeing it for some reason.

Comment: NB: you're missing the case for what to do if `power` is an _odd_ number.

Comment: `double t = power(base, power / 2) ; return t * t`

Comment: im very confused. this power mthod is jst to do x^n right ? the formula/identity still has to be done in another method.

Comment: and for odd powers, `return base * power(base, power - 1)`

Comment: @leoOrion the quoted identity is just an optimisation for even powers, with the generic case being the recursive rule in the comment preceding this one.

Comment: ah.. ok i read it wrongly. The edit makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Pow {
    public static void main(String $[]){
        System.out.println(pow(2,9));
    }
    public static double pow(double base, int power){
        if (power == 0)
            return 1;
        //even
        if((power&1)==0)
            return pow(base*base,power/2);
        //odd
        return base*pow(base,power-1);
    }
}
```

x<sup>n</sup> =  (x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n/2</sup> if n is **even**

x<sup>n</sup> =  x*x<sup>n-1</sup> if n is **odd**

Point of using this approach is to compute the power in **log(n)** because it is dividing the power by two when its even.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to account for the case where `power` is odd, and ideally also trap for the case when `power` is negative.

Just so that I'm not giving absolutely everything away, here's a JavaScript implementation:

```
function power(x, n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return undefined;             // uh-oh!
  } else if (n === 0) {
    return 1;                     // x^0 = 1
  } else if (n % 2 === 0) {
    const v = power(x, n / 2);    // optimisation for even powers
    return v * v;
  } else {
    return x * power(x, n - 1);   // general case - x^n = x * x^(n-1)
  }
}
```

You could also include an explicit test for `x^1`, but the code above works without it because the recursion terminates when it gets to calculating `x * (x ^ 0)`.